# Cart section "You May be Interested in..." Too Narrow

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

On the bottom left of my cart section of my [WooCommerce shop](http://www.dogsfirst.ie/shop/) there is a WooCommerce section entitled "You May be Interested in...", a cross sell for my customers. Problem is it's clearly too narrow, the image and info is squashed in a long column where there's clearly more space for it.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Conor

Comment: One thing I can recommend is loading your style sheet before your content, that page is all over the place.

Comment: To help the community you should put the code and a screenshot here. It will make the question live on and help other people.

Comment: I would advise using Firebug or Chrome's developer tools to examine the markup and related CSS. You can see that WooCommerce is applying it's column CSS grid for product lists `<ul class="products clearfix products-3"></ul>`... where `products-3` indicates it should try to display 3 columns of products. And yes, please add a screenshot.

Comment: I would also suggest to *not* use optimization/compression techniques while you are testing/requesting help. I can't look at your markup or your CSS while it is compressed. And don't load your CSS in the footer, you are getting a gnarly flash of unstyled content while you page loads.